# Removing special characters in XML data using java

Tags: java, xml

I am getting XML data from various external systems as part of intigration system. I am from IBM WMB back ground. I receive xml data max in 10KB size. I need to remove special characters in the XML before parse.  The data is receivng from virious country region its getting genarated various special characters like "ÿ" etc. Please help me how to remove all those such special characters in my xml. External system does not have control to remove those special characters.

Highy appriciated for your help.

Thanks,

Anil.

Comment: Why do you need to remove the "special" characters? `ÿ` is not a special character, it's a "y" with diaeresis - I doubt that it is correct to remove it. What is the actual problem that you are facing with these characters?

Comment: What counts as "special" - anything not in ASCII? Is this a problem in whatever is providing the text, and it should actually be something else, or is it correct data and you just need to make it simpler for the next system? Do you just want to remove the characters entirely, or convert them to the "nearest ASCII equivalent"?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. I need to remove all those special characters entirely . i need to remove all sepcial characters except Alpha Numeric,control characters and valid XML support characters.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [free command line tool](http://hll.nu/purchase/GetFreeXPL.htm) for transforming files with special characters in text to valid XML. It also assures that the file encoding matches what is specified in the declaration.

There is also a Java developer suite that allows you to use the parser to parse such files (called XPL) as an alternative to XML or a pre-process into XML. It uses a StAX-like process called StAX-PL.